# What is the plural of “remittance advice”?

Tags: irregular-plurals

The most common plural of “remittance advice” — a note sent by a customer paying a supplier, indicating that payment is on its way — seems to be “remittance advices”. However, I find that to be inelegant and I often suspect it is just plain made up! Unfortunately, the only alternatives I’ve come up with — “remittance advice notes”, “remittance advisements” and “remittance advisories” — are no more elegant, are not strict plurals of the original, and are absolutely made up.

Could anyone offer an argument as to why “remittance advices” is actually correct? Failing that, is there a better alternative than the ones I’ve listed?

Comment: Well it is certainly “correct” in terms of it being the ordinary and widely used plural in a range of sources from accounting software to the formal pronouncements of taxation authorities. But like you, I do find “advices” does not quite ring true. But then again, perhaps “a remittance advice” would generate the same dissonance if not for its idiomatic force. I think it’s because we are used to advice as uncountable (“I gave you advice” not “I gave you an advice”) and yet remittance advices are clearly countable.

Comment: Try ***remittance advisals***  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advisal

Comment: @jim. “Advisals” may be possible in American English, but is “remittance advisals” really an *idiomatic* possibility for the plural of “remittance advice”?

Comment: Google ngram viewer shows “advisal” is an extremely rare word (10 times less frequent that “antidisestablishmentarianism” and invisible on a scale against “advice”). A Google search (for me) produces no results for “remittance advisal” (and says, “Don’t you mean ‘remittance advice’?”) and a single result for the plural “remittance advisals”: https://www.visitrack.us/?page_id=14